# What is the best way to query previous slug name in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

### How to get postID?

Hi I am making a simple post detail page with NextJS.
I have my url: `[postID]/[title].tsx`

And for the post detail page, I want to query for `postID`: green highlighted area, so that I can fetch the post's data with it.

I use useRouter to get title name, so I am guessing I can do same thing to postID too.
How can I query for any slug key word like my case?

### My code

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React from 'react'

export default function Title() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const title = router.query.title
    // const postID = router.query... I want to get postID from url somehow.
  return (
    <div>{title}</div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are thinking of passing n level of slugs if I am not wrong.

Like this => `http://localhost:3000/postDetail/postId/title/city/tags`

Here in the URL above `postDetail` is your page and `postId/title/city/tags` are query params(slug)

**Solution**

1. Create a folder inside the pages folder (`pages/productDetail`)
2. And then create a file named `[...slug].js` inside `pages/productDetail`

**[...slug].js**

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Slug() {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.query.slug); // you will get an array of all query params here.. check your console...
  return (
    <>
      Pass data like http://localhost:3000/postDetail/postId/title/city/tags
    </>
  );
}
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-byg7wd?file=pages%2FproductDetail%2F%5B...slug%5D.js)**

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, Thank you so much!